# Cannot sort the child items

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to use jQuery Sortable to sort the items. For some reason I am not able to sort the child `li`, only the parent `li` can be moved and sorted. When I try to move the child `li`, it moves with the parent `ul`

```js
$( "#list-tree-pages" ).sortable({
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
  items: "> li",
  revert: true
});
$( "#list-tree-pages" ).disableSelection();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent-0 ui-sortable" id="list-tree-pages">
  <li class="item-3 has-children"><a href="#" class="drag ui-sortable-handle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a><a href="#">Features</a>
    <ul class="submenu" id="parent-3" style="display: block;">
      <li class="item-10"><a href="#" class="drag ui-sortable-handle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a><a href="#">Features 1</a></li>
      <li class="item-11"><a href="#" class="drag ui-sortable-handle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a><a href="#">Features 2</a></li>
      <li class="item-12"><a href="#" class="drag ui-sortable-handle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a><a href="#">Features 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry managed to solve the issue. It was with the JavaScript arguments. I have to remove the `>`

```
$( "#list-tree-pages" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    items: "li",
    revert: true
});
$( "#list-tree-pages" ).disableSelection();
```